# C# post string to sqlilte in utf8 encoding

Tags: c#, sqlite, utf-8

I post data which contains <kbd>Ö</kbd> and <kbd>Ş</kbd> not correctly posted to sqlite. I share a small part of my code in debug state.

```
queryString = "INSERT INTO " + LOCALDB_USER_TABLE_NAME +
                " (Username, UpdateTime, IpAddr, Synced) VALUES ('" +
                userName + "', '" + timestamp + "', '" + IPAddr + "', '" + synced + "')";
                _sourceDB.ExecuteNonQuery(queryString);
```

I open immediate window in visual studio and simply type these. Here I add <kbd>Ş</kbd> and <kbd>Ü</kbd> characters in utf8 to insert statement manually.

```
INSERT INTO adusers (Username, UpdateTime, IpAddr, Synced) VALUES ('CŞŞŞŞŞööööÖÜÜÜb', '2015-11-17T19:16:39.859434200Z', '192.168.0.7', '1')
```

I search smilar problems in stackoverflow and try this in i.w.:

```
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(queryString);
Expression has been evaluated and has no value
queryString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

and here how query string looks like in immediate window:

```
INSERT INTO adusers (Username, UpdateTime, IpAddr, Synced) VALUES ('CSSSSS��������b', '2015-11-17T19:16:39.859434200Z', '192.168.0.7', '1')
```

Data row in sqlite studio looks like same also so this is the problem (I can add utf8 character to sqlite database in studio). Something I mus do and query string should post data sqlilte with correct characters in utf8.

Comment: The database driver automatically converts between a `String`'s encoding and UTF-8. Don't re-encode manually.